# Dealing with changing views on Android in Angular: how can I ensure the app switches from web view to mobile view when orientation changes on tablet?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, ionic-framework

So the problem is to change views in angular android app. There are 2 views, mobile view and web view, but if I use tablet and open the app in landscape then it's in web view and after that I turn it in portrait then it will get stuck into web view and does not look good. I need it to go to mobile view if user changes the orientation with tablet. Any ideas how should I do it or any guides?

So the app has the mobile resolution when it goes to mobile view and it is right now 1024 and tablet I use is 1330. But I don't want it to be on mobile view if the tablet is landscape.

Comment: You can look into `window.matchMedia()` method. Particularly, you can initialize a var and asign it a value of `window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)")` and then add an event listener to the var to watch for the change. If you're controlling the UI with some var, you can combine it with this new var.